# How to run PostgreSQL Query every day with updated values?

Tags: sql, postgresql, scheduled-tasks

New to SQL, but trying to learn/do a job for a friend. I have a query set up that returns the number of bookings for the day. Example snippet:

```
...
WHERE be.event IN ('instant_approve', 'approve') AND TO_CHAR(be.created_at, 'yyyy-mm-dd') BETWEEN '2017-06-26' AND '2017-06-26';
```

Now, this query is set up for just today. How can I set this up so that tomorrow the query is executed for '2017-06-27' and so on? Is this possible?

Comment: Postgres is not MySQL. Try and tag appropriately.

Comment: It's also worth noting that you should have your `created_at` value in native `DATE` format, as conversions like that are a huge drag on performance.

Comment: Something like `... BETWEEN now() -'1day'::interval' and now()+'1 day'::interval`  (assuming a date type).

Comment: @tadman Conversions like that are not "huge drag on performance" at all. The main problem might be lack of index over `TO_CHAR(created_at, 'yyyy-mm-dd')`. Once this index created, the query will be fast, even if there are billions of rows.

Comment: @wildlasser this is not exactly what the author wanted to achieve -- your query will return records for 2 days time window, with shifted boundaries. So the query is fine, but `date_trunc('day', ...)` is needed, or again, `to_char(..., 'yyyy-mm-dd')`.

Comment: @Nick If you want to index on a function, sure, then it'll be "fine", but normalizing the data is usually a more effective solution.

Comment: In this scenario I'd recommend keep timestamps as is (8 bytes per each `timestamptz` or `timestamp`), w/o functional indexes or denormalization (`to_char()` will produce 10 bytes for each record), but rather use index on `created_at` and `date_trunc('day', ...)` -- as I've shown in my answer. This will be both performant and storage-efficient.

Comment: @tadman probably you were talking about not that type of denormalization that first jumped to my mind -- in this case, please explain your thought.

Comment: @nick I merely meant conforming to "norms", as in the native date format, not "normalizing" as in 1NF and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Built-in function `now()` gives you a timestamp of the beginning of your transaction (`CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` pseudo-constant is its "alias", a part of SQL standard, but I prefer using the function).

Another function, date_trunc() gives you a "truncated" timestamp and you can choose, how to truncate it. E.g., `date_trunc('day', now())` will give you the date/time of beginning of the current day.

Also, you can add or subtract intervals easily, so here is an example that gives you the beginning of the current and the next days:

```
select
  date_trunc('day', now()) cur_day_start,
  date_trunc('day', now() + interval '1 day') as next_day_start
;
```

Also, I would not use `to_char()` or anything else on top of `created_at` column -- this will not allow Postgres planner use index on top of this field. If you do want to use `to_char()`, then consider adding a functional index over `to_char(created_at, 'yyyy-mm-dd')`.

Here is how I would retrieve records generated at July 26, 2017:

```
where
  created_at between '2017-06-26' and '2017-06-27'
```

(implicit type casting from text to timestamps here)

This is equivalent to

```
where
  created_at >= '2017-06-26'
  and created_at <= '2017-06-27'
```

-- so all timestamps generated for July 26, 2017 will match. And for such query Postgres will use a regular index created for `created_at` column (if any).

"Dynamic" version:

```
where
  created_at between
    date_trunc('day', now())
    and date_trunc('day', now()) + interval '1 day'
```

Comment: a little changing of this code worked for me! appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Use current_date built-in function in the between condition and it will work only for today's bookings.
.........
WHERE be.event IN ('instant_approve', 'approve') AND TO_CHAR(be.created_at, 'yyyy-mm-dd') =current_date;

Comment: again, if number of rows is big, `TO_CHAR(be.created_at, 'yyyy-mm-dd')` will give you seq scan unless you've built a functional index over this expression.